# Change of time variable in Wiener process

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

I'm following a solution of an SDE from here

http://www.math.ethz.ch/~delbaen/ftp/preprints/CEV.pdf

Start with the SDE
$$
dX_t = \delta dt + 2\sqrt{X_t} dW_t
$$
consider a deterministic time change
$$
\tau = \frac{\sigma^2}{2\nu(2-\delta)}\left(1-\exp\left(-\frac{2\nu t}{2-\delta}\right)\right)
$$
the process $Y_t$ is defined as
$$
Y_t = exp(\nu t) X_{\tau}^{1-\delta/2}
$$
then, using Ito's lemma, we get
$$
dY_t = \nu Y_t dt + \sigma Y_t^{\frac{1-\delta}{2-\delta}} dW_t
$$

I'd like to understand how the Ito's lemma is applied here. The problem that I have is that when you write it, the $Y$ is derivated with respect to the $X$, but in the definition of $Y_t$ is used $\tau$, not $t$, in $X$, so there's a mixture between different times. How is this handled?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The time change described in the question may be handled as follows. Recall that if $W(t)$ is a standard Brownian motion then 
$$
W(\tau(b))-W(\tau(a))
$$ has the same distribution as 
$$
\int_a^b \sqrt{\tau'(t)} dW(t)
$$ where $a \le b$. Therefore the time-changed process $\tilde X_t = X_{\tau(t)}$ satisfies: 
$$
d \tilde X_{t} = \delta \tau'(t) dt + 2 \sqrt{ \tilde X_{t} } \sqrt{\tau'(t)} dW(t) \;.
$$
Now apply Ito's chain rule to $Y_t = \exp(\nu t) \tilde X_t^{1 - \delta/2}$ to obtain
$$
d Y_t = \nu Y_t dt + \exp(\nu t) (1-\frac{\delta}{2}) \tilde X_{t}^{-\delta/2} d \tilde X_{t} 
+\underbrace{\exp(\nu t) \left( 2 ( -\frac{\delta}{2} ) (1-\frac{\delta}{2}) \tau'(t) \tilde X_{t}^{-\delta/2} \right) dt}_{\text{Ito correction to standard chain rule}}  \;.
$$
Eliminate $\tilde X(t)$ to obtain the desired SDE for $Y_t$.

Comment: great, I never saw a change in the time coordinates until now actually. Do you have a reference where this is considered explicitly?

Comment: Check Oksendal's book, SDE: An introduction with applications.